# Find The Probability Density Function of Y=X/(X-1)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Would I use method of transformation for this problem? Can someone help steer me in the right direction on this? I have the answer but no idea how to get to it.

Let X be a continuous random variable with density function

f(x) = 2/(x^2) for x ≥ 2
 and 0 otherwise

Determine the density function of Y =
X/(X−1)
for 1 < y ≤ 2.

The way I am attempting to solve this is that I know x/(x-1) is decreasing. I am setting it up by method of transformation as P(x/(x-1) ≤ u)

Comment: Do you know [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar)? This is an alternative to what you are doing. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting.

Comment: Yes, you want to compute $P[Y\leq y]$ for $1<y\leq 2$, meaning $P[\frac{X}{X-1}\leq y]$, and the event $\{\frac{X}{X-1}\leq y\}$ is equivalent to $X\geq what$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_Y(y) 
&=&
P(Y\leq y)\\
&=&
P\left(\frac{X}{X-1}\leq y\right)\\
&=&
P\left(X\leq y(X-1)\right)\\
&=&
P\left(X\leq yX-y\right)\\
&=&
P\left(y\leq yX-X\right)\\
&=&
P\left(X \geq \frac{y}{y-1}\right)\\
&=&
\int_{\frac{y}{y-1}}^{\infty} 2x^{-2}dx\\
&=&
-2x^{-1}\Big|_{\frac{y}{y-1}}^{\infty}\\
&=&
2\frac{y-1}{y}\\
&=&
2(1-y^{-1})
\end{eqnarray*}
Check: $F_Y(1)=0$ and $F_Y(2)=1$. All good!

Now, $f_Y(y)=F_Y'(y) = 2y^{-2}$ on $(1,2]$ and zero otherwise.